# Jquery UI .dialog Opens and Closes Immediately with .click

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog attached to a link that opens but closes immediately. There are no JS errors in the console. Here's the code:

**JS Code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $( "##des-#pres_id#" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          show: "blind",
          hide: "explode"
       });

       $( "##link-des-#pres_id#" ).click(function() {
          $( "##des-#pres_id#" ).dialog( "open" );
          return false;
       });
    });
 </script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="des-#pres_id#" title="Description">#description#</div>
#left(description,30)#
<cfif len(description) GT 30> 
   <a href="" id="link-des-#pres_id#">more...</a>
</cfif>
```

What am i missing here?
(im using UI ver 1.7.2)

Comment: which template system uses #? could you provide some clean html?

Comment: coldfusion application requires #

Comment: well, as you know, the id selector in jquery uses #, but I don't thin that the # its the problem. did you tried removing the show and hide properties?

Comment: Thanks Cheluis for the help, that worked. Much appreciated

Comment: Oh, no problem. Glad to be helpful